# How do I efficiently check if data was returned in my GET request?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, get

I am webscraping and need to parse through a few thousand GET requests at a time. Sometimes these requests fail and I get 429 and/or 403 errors so I need to check if there is data before parsing the response. I wrote this function:

```
def check_response(response):
    if not response or not response.content:
        return False
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        if not soup or not soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "stuff"}):
            return False
    
    return True
```

This works, but it can take quite a while to loop through a few thousand responses. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you confirm that the value passed to *check_response()* is a return value from a *requests* call (get, post etc)

Comment: Yes, the value being passes is the return value from a GET request.

Comment: @Dunc Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you chose to accept Pingu's answer over mine? Is there something particularly wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `response.status_code` attribute to check the status code of the response. You can find a full list of HTTP error codes on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), but if it is >= 400, then it's definitely an error. Try using this code:

```
def check_response(response):
    if not response or not response.content or response.status_code >= 400:
        return False
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        if not soup or not soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "stuff"}):
            return False
    return True
```

Note that you need to indent your `return True` one level inwards, or else it will never be called because of the else-statement.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. The `return True` is fine as is though, as if the code makes it past `if not soup or not soup.find_all(...` then it will exit the else statement and `return True`.

Comment: Does this mean that, for example, HTTP 301 is valid? Did you consider *raise_for_status()*?

Comment: @Pingu `raise_for_status` wouldn't be particularly useful here because `.status_code` can do the same thing without needing to add a try-except. Also, I'm not handling redirects, but I'm assuming OP hasn't disabled `requests`'s default behavior to follow redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the comments by @Michael M I propose the following:

```
def check_response(response): # the value passed is a returned value from requests.get and therefore will never be falsy
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.txt, 'lxml')
        if soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "stuff"}):
            return True
    except Exception:
        pass
    return False
```